# Is the clamshell on the AN-72 what causes the Coanda effect?

Tags: jet-engine, wing, high-lift-device, stol

The [AN-72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-72) uses the [Coandă effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect) to improve lift and give it better STOL features.

In this image of an AN-72 (presumably on a takeoff roll) one can see a clam-shell bucket open at the top of the engine.

[image]
<sup>Source: Wikipedia site listed above</sup>

Is this clam shell what kept engine exhaust directed down over the wing to be used for Coandă effect lift enhancement? If not, what are these clam-shell doors for?

One can see in all the other images on that Wiki link that the doors are closed in flight including the first image showing an AN-72 on short final, presumably on a long enough runway that STOL procedures weren't necessary.

Comment: This is not a take-off roll for sure. The clamshells are the thrust reversers and the spoilers are extended.

Comment: I see that now, @DeepSpace, also noted in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those clam-shell doors are the engine **thrust reversers**. You can see them deploy together with the spoilers after landing in [this video](https://youtu.be/Z3xidJMdeBk?t=31):

[image: AN-72 landing]

In fact, you can also see deployed spoilers in your picture, therefore excluding that it shows a takeoff.

The Coandă effect is used by the normal engine exhaust: by placing the engines above the wing, the exhaust flows over the upper part of the wing, and the Coandă effect causes it to follow the wing's curvature.

Comment: I did wonder about that. Can't watch the video right now. Is there a clam shell below the wing, as well?

Comment: @FreeMan It doesn't look like it. I wonder if this is enough to re-direct all bypass flow. Maybe some of it is still exhausted backwards.

Comment: A "blown flap" generates *much more* extra lift than simply directing the thrust downward. It allows higher AoA without stall and boosts circulation (which boosts lift) at a given AoA.

Comment: And a blown flap is what this is. Even with the very loosest interpretation, it isn't really the Coanda effect. That will just mislead you as far as how the STOL characteristics are being enhanced here.